# Producing Mini Dumps for _caught_ SEH exceptions in mixed code DLL

Tags: c#, c++, interop, c++-cli, exception

I'm trying to use code similar to [clrdump](http://www.debuginfo.com/tools/clrdump.html) to create mini dumps in my managed process.

This managed process invokes C++/CLI code which invokes some native C++ static lib code, wherein SEH exceptions may be thrown (e.g. the occasional access violation).

```
  C# WinForms
  -> 
    C++/CLI DLL
    ->
      Static C++ Lib
      ->
        ACCESS VIOLATION
```

Our policy is to produce mini dumps for all SEH exceptions (caught & uncaught) and then translate them to C++ exceptions to be handled by application code. This works **for purely native** processes just fine; but when the application is a C# application - not so much.

The only way I see to produce dumps from SEH exceptions in a C# process is to **not** catch them - and then, as unhandled exceptions, use the `Application.ThreadException` handler to create a mini dump. The alternative is to let the CLR translate the SEH exception into a .Net exception and catch it (e.g. `System.AccessViolationException`) - but that would mean no dump is created, and information is lost (stack trace information in `Exception` isn't as rich as the mini dump).

So how can I handle SEH exceptions by both creating a minidump **and** translating the exception into a .Net exception so that my application may try to recover?

**Edit**

By "not catching exceptions" I also mean catching and then rethrowing, which does preserve the rich exception information.

Right now I'm considering never supressing `System.Exception` or anything deriving from `System.SystemException`. This means `AccessViolation` (and friends) always cause the program to end and produce a dump, and all other exceptions thrown need to derive from some sub-type (`ApplicationException`?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that with [Vectored Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681420(VS.85).aspx) I can get a first-chance notification of any SEH exception and use this occasion to produce a mini dump.